# Reponsivevoicejs TTS not working

Tags: html, text-to-speech

I have a simple webpage which i am trying to get text to speech so once a word is highlighted it will be spoken to the user using TTS. As i understand you only need one line of code which is the script can someone help me to possible issues as to why it isn't working.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?
family=Open+Sans" />
<script src="https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav-arrow" onClick="location.href='sam.html';"></div>
<div class="nav-arrow" >  </div>
<h2>Can you help Sam to draw a ship and sail across the ocean?</h2>
<div class='contain-boat'>
<div class='bottom'>
<div class='window'></div>
<div class='window window-2'></div>
<div class='window window-3'></div>
<div class='window window-4'></div>
</div>
<div class='pole'></div>
<div class='flag'></div>
<div class='sail'></div>
<div class='sail sail-2'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```